# MVC Centralized Forms Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, forms-authentication

I am switching from WebForms to MVC.

In the web.config of a WebForm I have the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/forms/Login"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

If the user is not already authenticated they are redirected to a separate app on the web server /forms/Login/?ReturnUrl=%2fforms%2fLoginClient. That app has a standard log in screen and connects to active directory to verify user credentials and then on success creates the cookie and redirects the user back to the originally requested page using:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false)
```

This is really convenient as I only have one login page UI to manage and all my code to talk to active directory in a single centralized location.  Additionally, for new apps all I need to do to provide authentication is add the snippet above into the web.config of the new app.

Is there an equivalent way to do this in an MVC project?

I am familiar with the option to include an Account controller when creating a new MVC application.
However, this has a lot of stuff I don't want and way more Views than I'll ever need.
I don't want to have to create a new login page or duplicate my active directory auth code for every new MVC application that I create.

Thanks for any guidance on this.

Comment: ASP.NET can use Forms authentication. If you already have it implemented on the site in other code, it'll work for the mvc part, just as it did the web forms part before.

Comment: @AndrewBarber So you are saying I should just be able to add the snippet above to the web.config of the MVC application and it will work?  When I try this it does correctly redirect me to the centralized log in application with the proper ReturnUrl in the query string but on successful log in it just redirects me back to the login page: /forms/Login/?ReturnUrl=%2fforms%2fLoginClient instead of redirecting to the ReturnURL.  Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: No. You do the *authentication* as you do now, but your authorization has to be by controller. And I think we'd need to see more to know what's going haywire.

Comment: @AndrewBarber So each app would need its own authentication controller?

Comment: No, it's done on the app's controllers/actions themselves. You set authorization for each action or the whole controller.